# Deleting the second last node from a LinkedList in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm working on a method that is supposed to delete the node prior to the last one,the logic seems quite fine with me, but when I tried to implement it in a project, it didn't work out. ( Oh and I'm using MyLinkedList)

here's the code:

```
public void deleteSec(){
    Node current = head;
    Node p = head.next;
    Node q = null;

    while(p.next!=null){
        q = current;
        current.next = p;
        p = p.next;
    }
    q.next = p; // q.next = q.next.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your LL is empty? head will be null and this will cause an exception when you call head.next;

you have to take care of special cases like: empty LL, LL with one node, LL with two nodes.

Here is my code:

```
public void deleteSec() {
    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (head.next == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (head.next.next == null) {
        head = head.next;
        return;
    }
    Node current = head;
    Node p = current.next;
    Node q = p.next;
    while (q.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
        p = p.next;
        q = q.next;
    }
    current.next = q;
}
```

Comment: I implemented the above code and printed the list afterwards, there's no change to the list

Comment: Last line: current.next = q; not current.next = p;

I modified the code

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myLinkedList.size() > 1) {
    myLinkedList.remove(myLinkedList.size()-2);
}
```

Comment: That's something i thought of, but what is wrong with the code I provided ?

Comment: It won't be readable.  It should make sense, because we are removing from the list not removing from the node itself.  There are many issues in the approach.  If you want to iterate over it use a listIterator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)

Comment: What if you don't aware of the size of the LinkedList ? I want to remove the nth element from the end in single iteration.

Comment: @SumanthVarada, if n is from 0 to n, then just user .remove(n) or from the other side .size() - n

Answer (score 0):

well i personally compiled it,

Assuming the node class is named Node and you have a getNext() method that returns the next Node or null if this Node is the last node, you would do something like this.

```
if (head == null) // or if (first == null)
{
return; // There are no elements in the list.
}
Node currect = head; // This is the head, or Node current = first;
Node previous = null;
while (current.getNext() != null)
{
previous = current;
currrent = current.getNext();
}

Then do this to make the second to last pointer to next null.
if (previous != null)
{
previous.setNext( null );
}
else
{
// The list has 1 entry only.
head = null; // or first = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If deleting a second last node would be a common operation, as it is in my case, I would suggest an extra `prev` or `previous` node added to the `Node` construction.

Usually a linked list node would be

```
private static class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> next;
}
```

But I modified it to be like

```
private static class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> prev;
    private Node<Item> next;
}
```

Thus, if you want to delete the second last, the implementation would be pretty straightforward:

```
oldSecondLast = last.prev; // Assumes last points to the last node
oldSecondLast.next = last;
last = oldSecondLast.prev;
oldSecondLast = null; // To avoid loitering
```